# Confusing recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm going back to the basics about python and got really confused about recursions, here's a really simple sample code I used,

```py
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        print('Return Value 1')
        return 1
    else:
        print('Recursively calling factorial: ',n-1)
        result = n*factorial(n-1)
        print('Returning: ', result)
        return result
```

Calling  factorial(5) it outputs

```
    Recursively calling factorial:  4
    Recursively calling factorial:  3
    Recursively calling factorial:  2
    Recursively calling factorial:  1
    Return Value 1
    Returning:  2
    Returning:  6
    Returning:  24
    Returning:  120
```

I was confused because why does it first prints all the 'Recursively calling factorial:' then all the results in ascending order?

I was expecting python to read line by line and an output as something like this but I was wrong.

```
    Recursively calling factorial:  4
    Returning:  120
    Recursively calling factorial:  3
    Returning:  24
```

Comment: then you should do a read up on recursive, use a debugger

Comment: It does read it line by line... `result = n*factorial(n-1)` this line happens before `print('Returning: ', result)`

Comment: I mean im trying to visualize it. From what I understand its like going back through time when n = 1 ? or maybe Im over analyzing this...

Comment: @orlevii so it "holds" the results until it reaches n = 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thought experiment you can go through when trying to understand recursion is to convert the problem into regular function calls and then the recursion itself disappears, but nested function calls remain:

```py
def factorial1(n):
    print('Return Value 1')
    return 1

def factorial2(n):
    print('Recursively calling factorial: ', n - 1)
    result = n * factorial1(n - 1)
    print('Returning: ', result)
    return result

def factorial3(n):
    print('Recursively calling factorial: ', n - 1)
    result = n * factorial2(n - 1)
    print('Returning: ', result)
    return result

def factorial4(n):
    print('Recursively calling factorial: ', n - 1)
    result = n * factorial3(n - 1)
    print('Returning: ', result)
    return result

def factorial5(n):
    print('Recursively calling factorial: ', n - 1)
    result = n * factorial4(n - 1)
    print('Returning: ', result)
    return result

print(factorial5(5))
```

If you follow the pattern of function calls (eg `factorial5()` calls `factorial4()`) you will see the order in which program statements are executed.

Answer (score 0):

The functions calls itself until reaching the case where n==1 — then when that function returns its value the iteration that can call it can return a value using it, and then the iteration that was waiting for that value can return its calculation. Etc.

In Python’s C implementation there is a limit as to the number of times you can do this — which means I’m always a bit cautious about using recursion for very complicated problems.

Comment: Thank you for this definition its also the same to the pdf im reading A Beginners
Guide to Python 3 Programming by John Hunt. I just get confused about the arrangement in the printing of values

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple, your function will execute this way until being called with 1

- Printing the recursive call
- Evaluating n * factorial(n-1), and to do so it will be recursively call the factorial (before printing the result)

When it reach 1, it prints the returned valued 1, and the what's left of each function that has been recursively called before (i.e. the printing of the result of n * factorial(n-1)).

- So before calling it with 1, it was called with 2, 2 * factorial(1) will print 2
- Before being called with 2 it was called with 3, 3 * factorial(2) will print 3
- and so on

Comment: So its starts with 1*2*3*4*5 NOT 5*4*3*2*1 . I think I can visualize it now thank you